# R - Remove blanks from data frame

Tags: r, if-statement

An example of the data frame I have is:

```
Index  TimeDifference
1        
2         
3            20
4      
5            67
```

I want to delete all rows that are blank (these are blank and NOT na). Hence the following data frame I want is:

```
Index     TimeDifference
3               20
5               67
```

Thanks

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `TimeDifference` is a character column:

```
df <- data.frame(Index=1:5, TimeDifference=c("","","20","","67"))
```

Then you can use:

```
df[-which(df$TimeDifference==""),]
```

or

```
df[!(df$TimeDifference==""),]
```

or

```
df[df$TimeDifference!="",]
```

which gives:

```
  Index TimeDifference
3     3             20
5     5             67
```

Comment: These are perfect :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df[as.character(df$TimeDifference)!= "" ,]
```

Comment: This works! Thank you :D